# unable to find site key to bypass recapcha

Tags: selenium, recaptcha, 2captcha

when I'm going to bypass google recapcha v2 with 2capcha and anticapcha  I'm unable to find the site key in SoundCloud its contains with iframe with src tag much appreciate your help to find the site key in Soundcloud

Answer (score 4, accepted):

switch to "Network" tab and find a request to "reload?k=sitekey" k= represent site key

Answer (score 0):

here's invisible captcha so it performs request to google api for response.

this is yours https:/ /www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor?ar=1&k=strong text
and this should be data-sitekey
6Lexz1YUAAAAAJZknL3EkeY_xBlIKGKGfGwFHhjK